# OpenCV : 2d - 3d point correspondence using chessboard

Tags: python, opencv

I'm facing a problem when I try to find the correspondences between a 3D point located on my chessboard and its position on the image taken by the camera.

Here is what I do:

I use the method

```
corners = cv.FindChessboardCorners(frameGray, patternSize, cv.CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv.CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
```

which gives me the position of all the internal corners of the chessboard. Because I know their positions in the real world I would like to use further the solvePnP method to find the camera pose.

However, I noticed that the "corner order" changes depending of the orientation of my chessboard. I want to draw a green circle on my "first" corner but that "first" corner is different depending on my chessboard orientation.

Here are some screenshots to explain what I am talking about:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cYtUIDy.png]
  [image: http://i.imgur.com/04wvzL7.png]

And here is the full code:

```
import cv


patternSize = (7,7)#interior number of corners, that is, points, where the black squares touch each other

cv.NamedWindow("w1", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
camera_index = 0
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)
c = cv.WaitKey(5000)#wait for the camera to be initialized
def repeat():
    global capture #declare as globals since we are assigning to them now
    global camera_index
    global frame
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)  
    if frame:       
            cv.ShowImage("w1", frame)
            #convert to grayImage 
            frameGray = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
            cv.CvtColor(frame,frameGray,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

            corners = cv.FindChessboardCorners(frameGray, patternSize, cv.CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv.CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
            if (len(corners[1]) == patternSize[0]*patternSize[1]):#if we found all the internal corners
                    #Refines the corner locations
                    #cv.FindCornerSubPix(frameGray,corners[1],(11,11),(-1,-1),(cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10, 0.01))
                    point = int(corners[1][0][0]), int(corners[1][0][1])
                    print (point)
                    patternWasFound = corners[0]
                    #cv.DrawChessboardCorners(frame, patternSize, corners[1], patternWasFound)
                    cv.Circle(frame, point, 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)
                    cv.ShowImage("w1",frame)
            c = cv.WaitKey(10)
while True:
    repeat()
```

As you can see I always take the same corner (int(corners[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6pXm.png)[0][0]), int(corners[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6pXm.png)[0][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6pXm.png))), but it changes depending on my chessboard orientation.

Is there anyone who knows why ? If the corner location changes, I can't know the corresponding real coordinates then :/

Thank you !

Comment: How is OpenCV supposed to know that? If you rotate your board by 90 degrees, the chessboard looks exactly the same. You could try to use a non-square chessboard. That would be less ambiguous. If that is not an option, you need to come up with your own heuristic, which of the 4 possible rotations is the correct one and reorder the points accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the problem is that I'm not even rotating my board by 90°, I'm just moving my chessboard horizontally and it seems the green point is changing.

Comment: I did not assume that. But in your two images you are tilting it a little bit. And with a square board OpenCV cannot distinguish between a 10 degrees rotation in one direction or an 80 degree rotation in the other direction. One could of course assume that the rotation change between images should be minimal. But OpenCV processes each image independently and therefore cannot take such things into account. But you could by doing some postprocessing of the results. Or you could try a non-square board first. Just to check.

Comment: You were right, I changed my chessboard for a non-square one and it fixed my problem :) Thank you very much !